# OSX Fuerte Install Homebrew Conflicts

Tags: ros, homebrew, ros-fuerte, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am following the instructions [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/OSX/Homebrew/Source) to install Fuerte on OSX using Homebrew. I have run into a number of problems with the Homebrew Formulae provided by the ros/fuerte tap, including

1. The swig-wx formula is broken. A partial fix is listed [here](http://ardadv.blogspot.co.uk/2012/05/using-ros-robot-operating-system-fuerte.html) but this should be included in the official tap.
2. This swig-wx formula doesn't appear to support the -php5 flag which other rosdep brews seems to need (e.g. graphviz).
3. If I install the ros/fuerte/qt version, I can't install pyside as I get segfaults when generatorrunner is  run. (I haven't looked at this in detail)

My question is where is the correct place to report these bugs and discuss fixes (and also to help me understand why we need particular special formulae)? Is it here or github? If it's the latter, where is the correct issue board?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33823/osx-fuerte-install-homebrew-conflicts/) by [hawesie](https://answers.ros.org/users/246/hawesie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 282 on 2012-05-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is the correct forum for asking questions about this, or you can raise issues on the ros-osx mailing list: http://kforge.ros.org/mailman/listinfo/rososx-mailinglist

I have tried to answer you questions on github, but long story short, fuerte is still broken on OS X right now.

The idea of having a ros version of qt (separate from the latest version in Homebrew) came from wanting to mimic the stable versions provided by distributions like Ubuntu.  The idea was that static versions would help keep the Homebrew installation working, but now that I have been working on it for while, I think it will be better to let the Homebrew dependencies float and fix problems as they come up.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2012-05-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hawesie](https://answers.ros.org/users/246/hawesie/) on 2012-05-12**:
I agree. My brief experience with this is that maintaining fixed versions on Homebrew seems to be a a bit of a pain in the ass.

**Comment by [hawesie](https://answers.ros.org/users/246/hawesie/) on 2012-05-12**:
It may also be worth adding the "still broken" part to the install page, as people will inevitably see the official page and assume they will be able to make it work.

**Comment by [hawesie](https://answers.ros.org/users/246/hawesie/) on 2012-05-12**:
I agree. My brief experience with this is that maintaining fixed versions on Homebrew seems to be a a bit of a pain in the ass.

**Comment by [hawesie](https://answers.ros.org/users/246/hawesie/) on 2012-05-12**:
I agree. My brief experience with this is that maintaining fixed versions on Homebrew seems to be a a bit of a pain in the ass.